# How does requests handle the proxy list?

Tags: python, proxy

I am not able to google an answer so I ask here.

Let's say I have a very simple code like this:

```
import requests  
proxies = {
    'http': 'http://proxy.example.com:8080',
...
...
...
    'https': 'http://secureproxy.example.com:8090',
 }  
url = 'http://mywebsite.com/example'  
response = requests.get(url, proxies=proxies)
```

When the request function uses a long list of proxy server ip address.

Does it submit the request to ALL ip address in the list?

Or does it stop if one of the the proxy works?

Answer (score 0):

I wasn't able to find direct hint in some documentation either. However, i put together some test code to verify that (on my Mac OS X ):

- there was no automatic proxy failover
- always the last entry in proxy list is used as proxy
- if connection fails, requests library performs automatic retries to connect to the proxy

Python3 code:

```
import requests
proxies = {
  'http': '<proxy 1>',
  'http': '<proxy 2>',
  'http': '<proxy 3>',
  #'http': 'notexisting.asdfasvjkdfsalkghhsljgkfhsdfghljkfsdhhlk.com:3128',
}
print("Use tcpdump to verify connection and data on the wire (make sure to adjust port numbers to match the ports of your configured proxies):")
print("sudo tcpdump -i any -n port 8888 or port 3128 -s 0 -A")
# head request will not return body!
response = requests.head('http://www.daujones.com', proxies=proxies)
# The response
print (f"{response.status_code} {response.reason}")
# Prints the proxy which has been used
print (f"{response.connection.proxy_manager.keys()}")
# For completeness, all keys of available data in response
print (f"{response.__dict__.keys()}")
```